# Употребление слова люблю

Tags: грамотная-речь

Пожалуйста, подскажите, возможно ли употребление слова люблю по отношению к неодушевленным предметам, например, "я люблю свой компьютер"?
Разве не правильно будет "я люблю сидеть за своим компьютером", или "я люблю играть в компьютерные игры"?

Comment: Это совершенно нормально; а вот избегать следует употребления слова "поклонник" (вместо "любитель") по отношению к неодушевлённым сущностям и животным. Это явление на совести тележурналистов (поклонники футбола, рыбной ловли или немецких овчарок).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вполне возможно.
В русском языке глагол "любить" означает не только "испытывать влечение к кому-то", но и "нравиться что-то делать", "получать удовольствие" и т. д.

> ЛЮБИТЬ, люблю, любишь; любящий; любимый; -бим, -а, -о; любя; нсв.
>   кого-что. 1. Чувствовать глубокую привязанность к кому-, чему-л., быть
>   преданным кому-, чему-л. Л. мать. Л. своих детей. Л. Родину. //
>   Испытывать чувство расположения, симпатии к кому-л. Солдаты любили
>   своего командира. Л. школьных друзей. Л. маленьких детей. 2. (кого).
>   Чувствовать сердечную склонность к лицу другого пола; быть влюблённым.
>   Л. девушку. Л. женатого человека. Л. впервые в жизни. Л. жену. 3. что,
>   с инф. и с придат. дополнит. Чувствовать склонность, интерес,
>   влечение, тяготение к чему-л. Л. читать стихи. Л. театр. Л. работать в
>   огороде. Л. свою профессию. Л. книги. // Испытывать удовольствие от
>   созерцания, ощущения чего-л. Л. ехать в поезде. Л. цветы. Л. острые
>   приправы. Он любил петь. Л. играть в шахматы. Л., когда поют песни.
>   Дочь любит, чтобы ей рассказывали сказки. * Люблю грозу в начале мая
>   (Тютчев). 4. Нуждаться в чём-л. как в необходимом (благоприятном)
>   условии своего существования, обитания (о животных, растениях). Цветы
>   любят воду. Сосны любят песчаную почву. Огурцы любят тепло. Рыба любит
>   чистую воду.

[Источник](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)